# Nginx & Varnish connection error

Tags: wordpress, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

My site gives error 521 all the times.

When I found this error from my server

```
$sudo service varnish reload
* Reloading HTTP accelerator varnishd
Connection failed (localhost:6082)
Error: vcl.load 8d6fb6be-9a0a-4896-be47-e2678e3c2617 /etc/varnish/default.vcl failed
```

Moreover,
`varnishlog`
shows nothing.

I am following this tutorial to set the server up. And, I changed

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
    -T localhost:6082 \
    -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
    -u www-data -g www-data \
    -S /etc/varnish/secret \
    -s malloc,256m"
```

The `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` file is copied from the [tutorial](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/using-nginx-php-fpmapc-and-varnish-to-make-wordpress-websites-fly/). All `&amp;` has been corrected to `&`.

It is a fresh VPS. No firewall.

Any clue to resolve it?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

3 things come into my mind:

1. Start varnish in foreground mode and check what it says

   ```
   varnishd -F -a :80 \
   -T localhost:6082 \
   -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
   -u www-data -g www-data \
   -S /etc/varnish/secret \
   -s malloc,256m
   ```
2. Try changing *-T localhost:6082* to *-T 127.0.0.1:6082*
3. Your port 6082 might be already taken. Change it or check if it's listed in already open ports' list with

   ```
   netstat -tlnep
   ```

Answer (score 1):

restart your varnish

```
sudo /etc/init.d/varnish restart
```

then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/varnish reload
```